# Maven Support Issues on MacBook M1

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, apple-m1

The TestNG Appium Mobile Java project works well on the intelChip based Mac's but throws error on M1 Macs. When try to add framework support as Maven it does not recognize and the error:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 (Community Edition)/
> Java 1.8.0_372

```
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unrecognized option: --add-exports
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerConnectorImpl$StartServerTask.run(MavenServerConnectorImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Please add add the version of IntelliJ and java you are using. IntelliJ had some issues with apple chips in older versions. Ensure you are using the latest version of intellij/plugins (and maybe java).

Comment: Can you double-check that Intel and M1 setup ups are identical?
This issue has been known to happen if you are using a JDK older than JDK 11
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_runner_jdk

Comment: I have to use Java 1.8 unfortunately